# fail to execute examples in hexagon-dsp: cannot link executable library adsprpc.lib

Tags: android, sdk, hexagon-dsp

I have successfully built and executed the calculator app with `hexagon-sim`, `android` and `hvx`. However, reproducing the same `make` flow does not succeed in executing other applications on my `Open-Q 820 board`.

For instance: Application `bilateral_v60`, even though I successfully make and push the executable, `android.lib` and also `skel.lib`  on the board, upon executing the command:

```
adb shell ADSP_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib/rfsa/adsp /data/bilateral_v60
```

the board fails to execute. Here is the execution error:

```
No arguments given, using defaults: 1920 1080 1 33333 1000 12000 0.
return value from dspCV_initQ6() : -1 
src/bilateral_v60.c:197::error: -1: 0 == retVal
error: -1
calling dspCV_deinitQ6()... 
return value from dspCV_deinitQ6(): -1 
- failure
```

Comment: Can you include more details (the exact error messages, exact command executed, SDK version used)?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @Brian. I have found that it might be a global issue on my board as the `calculator` is not getting executed neither due to the same issue. Will try to flash the whole android and retry and report back here.

Comment: after flash the error resolved with the execution error. Please have a look at my updated question @BrianCain.

Comment: Can you show the output from `adb logcat`?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a tampered library file on the board. Downloading and reflashing the Android image from Intrynsic website solved my issue.